# Mongo shell ssl command

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongo shell to connect to a mongoDB database on a server. When I simply type "mongo --ssl" in my windows command line. It says "--ssl" is not recognized. The [website](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/) says most mongo distribution now include SSL support and I download the Windows 64-bit 2008 r+ from the [download page](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production). Did I get a wrong distribution? I find the legacy version does not support SSL, but I don't know if the 2008 r2 support or not. Or, am I supposed to configure mongod and mongos for ssl? I'm connecting to a remote server with ssl enabled in its mongod and mongos. I wonder if this is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find out the ssl support versions can be found from [here](https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl), although they are 32-bits (on the website they says they might not support 32-bits in the later versions). It's a pity that I cannot get the 64bit community distribution with ssl support. The Windows 64-bit 2008 r+ on the download page don't support ssl, but they only put notice on the legacy editions. This is really confusing. Hope this might be helpful for those people who encounter the same problem as mine.